# Sending DateTime from .Net to Java Web Service

Tags: c#, java, .net, web-services

I am having some issues with a Java web service i have consumed into my simple outlook add in that i am trying to integrate with this 3rd party API.  The problem is the difference between .Net dates and Java ones, i will be honest i do not know much about Java anymore.  My problem is that the API is expecting a date in the format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` which is fine, but when i try and create that using something like DateTime.ParseExact i recieve an error stating that "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."  Not really sure what my options our as Google has not really helped me out this time.

Comment: It's not clear from your question - are you looking for help parsing at the .NET side, formatting from the .NET side, or one of those on the Java side? Please give a sample string and the code the you've tried.

Comment: Have you captured the string that's causing the failure to see what it actually looks like?  ParseExact should work if your format is defined correctly, no matter what the format.

Comment: Can you post your parsing code?

Comment: Is this webservice really expecting the date as a string rather than as an `xsd:datetime`?

Comment: The webservice states it is expecting a DateTime (thats what it is asking for) but the documentation states it should be in yyyyMMddHHmmss format which is why i have been trying to use ParseExact.  @Jon Skeet, Sorry if i wasnt clear, i am consuming a Java Webservice on a .Net client.

Answer (score 0):

I think was doing something wrong, i wasnt formatting the date in the correct format before using parse exact:

```
string fd = new DateTime(2010, 07, 10, 01, 00, 00).ToString();
string sd = new DateTime(2010, 07, 10, 23, 59, 59).ToString();

fd = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", DateTime.Parse(fd));
sd = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", DateTime.Parse(sd));

api.searchMessage(null,
     null,
     null,
     "nosort",
     "archivedate",
     DateTime.ParseExact(fd, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null),
     DateTime.ParseExact(sd, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null),
     100);
```

Not sure if it will return data, but at least it is not erroring

Comment: That looks like you are passing a date object to the api method, not a string in the format yyyyMMddHHmmss... If the API is fine with that then this is good. In fact generally you seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary conversions from date to string and back again... That may be test code but if its final code its a bit of a mess...

Comment: yeah its test code, just trying to get my head around passing the date around, and this is really a proof of concept.  When consumed the API is expecting a DateTime not a string but the API documentation (what little of it there is) is telling me to pass it in that format.

Answer (score -3):

On the .NET side, you should be able to do something like this:

```
// convert DateTime to string
return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// convert string to DateTime
if(value.Length != 14)
    throw new ArgumentException("Value must be 14 characters.");
int year = Int32.Parse(value.Substring(0, 4));
int month = Int32.Parse(value.Substring(4,2));
int day = Int32.Parse(value.Substring(6,2));
int hour = Int32.Parse(value.Substring(8,2));
int minute = Int32.Parse(value.Substring(10,2));
int second = Int32.Parse(value.Substring(12,2));
return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0);
```

The manual string parsing with substrings is a bit hoakey, but it technically works.
Hope it helps!